# Como classificar array pela chave e pelo valor, sem perder o valor original da chave?

Tags: php

Já tentei de todas as formas.

A array pura, está assim:

```
Array
(
 [71] => 100
 [70] => 100
 [69] => 23.53
 [68] => 74.07
 [67] => 23.29
 [66] => 61.01
 [59] => 100
 [3] => 35
 [1] => 56.18
)
```

Quando aplico um `asort($array)` fica assim:

```
Array
(
 [67] => 23.29
 [69] => 23.53
 [3] => 35
 [1] => 56.18
 [66] => 61.01
 [68] => 74.07
 [71] => 100
 [70] => 100
 [59] => 100
)
```

Quando tento um `rsort($array)`, perde o valor original da Key.

```
Array
(
 [0] => 100
 [1] => 100
 [2] => 100
 [3] => 74.07
 [4] => 61.01
 [5] => 56.18
 [6] => 35
 [7] => 23.53
 [8] => 23.29
)
```

Necessito que fique assim:

```
Array
(
 [59] => 100
 [70] => 100
 [71] => 100
 [68] => 74.07
 [66] => 61.01
 [1] => 56.18
 [3] => 35
 [69] => 23.53
 [67] => 23.29
)
```

Se fosse um SELECT no MysQl, seria fácil.
Bastaria aplicar um ORDER BY CHAVE DESC, VALOR ASC.
Mas na Array, não estou conseguindo fazer.

Comment: Qual é o resultado esperado?

Comment: Editei a questão e inseri o resultado que eu preciso no final.

Comment: A ordenação é pelo value?

Comment: Tentou com o [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)?

Comment: Tenta o `arsort`

Comment: O arsort quase funcionou. Só faltou deixar as KEY ascendente. Ficou assim: 
 Array
(
    [71] => 100
    [70] => 100
    [59] => 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como `asort` funcionou, você pode continuar usando e reverta o `array` usando `array_reverse` com o segundo parâmetro `true`, deixando o segundo parâmetro como `true` as suas `keys` não são alteradas.

```
<?php

$array = array
(
 71 => 100,
 70 => 100,
 69 => 23.53,
 68 => 74.07,
 67 => 23.29,
 66 => 61.01,
 59 => 100,
 3 => 35,
 1 => 56.18
);


echo "<pre>";
var_export($array);
asort($array);
var_export(array_reverse($array, true));
```

## Saída

**Array original**

```
array (
  71 => 100,
  70 => 100,
  69 => 23.530000000000001,
  68 => 74.069999999999993,
  67 => 23.289999999999999,
  66 => 61.009999999999998,
  59 => 100,
  3 => 35,
  1 => 56.18,
)
```

**Array ordenado**

```
array (
  59 => 100,
  70 => 100,
  71 => 100,
  68 => 74.069999999999993,
  66 => 61.009999999999998,
  1 => 56.18,
  3 => 35,
  69 => 23.530000000000001,
  67 => 23.289999999999999,
)
```

[Executar](http://tpcg.io/cblXhZ)

Comment: Wictor, Note que eu preciso dos valores Decrescentes e das chaves Crescentes.

Comment: Editei com a saída da forma como você deseja :)

Comment: Wictor. Deu certo! Cara... nem acredito! O dia inteiro. No Stack em inglês, ninguem conseguiu. Valeu mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Apesar da resposta aceita funcionar para esta array em específica, ela pode não funcionar para outras arrays. O `array_reverse` só funcionou porque a array original já estava com as chaves em ordem decrescente.

Para classificar a array com valores decrescentes e as chaves crescentes, nesta ordem de importância, isto é, colocando as chaves de valores iguais em ordem crescente, você precisa primeiro ordenar as chaves em ordem crescente e depois ordenar os valores em ordem decrescente.

### Array de entrada

```
$arr = array(
 71 => 100,
 70 => 100,
 69 => 23.53,
 68 => 74.07,
 67 => 23.29,
 66 => 61.01,
 59 => 100,
 3 => 35,
 1 => 56.18,
);
```

### [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) - Ordenar as chaves da menor para a maior

```
ksort($arr);
```

### [arsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) - Ordenar os valores do maior pro menor mantendo as chaves

```
arsort($arr);
```

### Array de Saída

```
Array ( 
    [59] => 100 
    [70] => 100 
    [71] => 100 
    [68] => 74.07 
    [66] => 61.01 
    [1] => 56.18 
    [3] => 35 
    [69] => 23.53 
    [67] => 23.29 
)
```